# Finding the next occurrence of a given date with MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently working on a database that stores software licensing information such as software name, purchase date, cost, quantity, etc... After the software has been owned for 12 months, we must pay a maintenance fee.

My question therefore, is how to design a query that will take the purchase date and compute the next occurrence of that date to be stored in the maintenance date field. Ex) If a license was purchased on 12/31/1999, I would need to pay maintenance on 12/31/2016.

I don't have a lot of experience with MS Access or SQL queries, and after researching this for a while, I am not even sure this is possible. I would appreciate any help you guys could give me!

Comment: Look into [DateAdd()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php) available in Access SQL and VBA, allowing you to add across many time intervals (day, week, month, year).

Comment: Will do, thanks for the tip!

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will do exactly this:

```
Public Function DateNextAnnualDay( _
    ByVal AnnualDay As Date) _
    As Date

    Dim SomeDate        As Date
    Dim NextAnnualDay   As Date
    Dim Years           As Integer

    SomeDate = Date

    NextAnnualDay = AnnualDay
    Years = DateDiff("yyyy", AnnualDay, SomeDate)
    If Years < 0 Then
        ' Don't calculate hypothetical annual days.
    Else
        NextAnnualDay = DateAdd("yyyy", Years, AnnualDay)
        If DateDiff("d", SomeDate, NextAnnualDay) <= 0 Then
            ' Next annual day falls earlier in the year than SomeDate.
            NextAnnualDay = DateAdd("yyyy", Years + 1, AnnualDay)
        End If
    End If

    DateNextAnnualDay = NextAnnualDay

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax

```
SELECT DateAdd("yyyy",1,[MyDate]) AS MaintDate
FROM Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do more complicated querying you can write a function in a module and then access it in a query using VBA. For instance you can iterate through a loop to match a condition

```
Function GetNextDate(ByVal dteOriginalDate As Date) As Date

While dteOriginalDate <= DateTime.Now

    dteOriginalDate = DateAdd("Yyyy", 1, dteOriginalDate)

Wend

GetNextDate = dteOriginalDate

End Function
```

Will iterate adding one year from the original date to the point at which the date is in the future. You can the build it into a query (using right-click -> build) so that each row runs through your code and applied the logic.

This will allow you to store the original licence date in your database and calculate the next due date without having to know (or amend) the intervening years.